# vba excel shape

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

I've used a small subroutine to insert a picture into my sheet by

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL).Select
```

This works fine with Excel 2003 (Windows), but does not work with Excel 2011 (Mac) any more.

Therefore I modified my subroutine
(like proposed http://www.launchexcel.com/google-maps-excel-demo/),
but the subroutine stops at

```
theShape.Fill.UserPicture URL
```

with the error message

"-2147024894 (80070002) Fehler der Methode UserPicture des Objekts FillFormat"

The rectangle is green!

```
Sub Q1()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim URL As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim theShape As Shape
Dim pasteCell As Range

' Used Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Blatt1")

' Delete already existing shapes
For Each theShape In wks.Shapes
        theShape.Delete
Next theShape

' Check all existing rows in Column K
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow

' the URLs are already computed and stored in column K
URL = wks.Range("K" & i).Value

' try to put the images in column L
Set pasteCell = wks.Range("L" & i)
pasteCell.Select

' Create a Shape for putting the Image into
' ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL).Select is deprecated and does not work any more!!!
Set theShape = wks.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, pasteCell.Left, pasteCell.Top, 200, 200)

' fill the shape with the image after greening
theShape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
theShape.Fill.UserPicture URL

Next i

End Sub
```

Any suggestions or hints? Probably I'm blind as a bat....

Comment: Have you made sure that the URL you're referencing is actually an image? I am using Excel 2010 (Windows), but your sub worked fine (I used an example Google Maps URL). I would look at the value of `URL`. You may have a malformed link.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But the URL is ok. I use a Google API too and, as I mentioned, this works with Excel 2003. I haven't changed the content of my sheet. And I tested the UserPicture-method with a given URL and it doesn't work.
For the moment I think the problem could depend on settings of my MS-Office. Any experiences?

Comment: There's a difference between URL and local file access: 
`theShape.Fill.UserPicture "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?_&location=51.501554,-0.178082&size=512x512&heading=135&fov=100&pitch=0&sensor=false"`

ends with the error

`theShape.Fill.UserPicture "Macintosh HD:Library:User Pictures:Flowers:Flower.tif"`

works!!

Comment: @TomThumb So, I take it the difference between the URL and local file access was the issue? What was your solution?

Comment: @JackOrangeLantern
Sorry, I have no solution.... I need the URL access!
Meanwhile I tested the code with Excel 2007 (Windows) and it worked!
I'm a little bit confused for the moment ...

Comment: @TomThumb I tried to use the `Set` method to set shape properties rather than the deprecated `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL).Select` in a stand-alone sub, and it worked very well with both .jpg and .png files from URLs. I have adapted the sub to your code and posted it - give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried syntax along the lines of this for setting a shape to a URL:

```
Sub Picadder()

Dim Pic As Shape

Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("http://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 100, 100)

End Sub
```

This code, when adapted to your efforts, might look something along the lines of this:

```
Sub Q1()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim URL As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim theShape As Shape
Dim pasteCell As Range

' Used Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("Blatt1")

' Delete already existing shapes
For Each theShape In wks.Shapes
        theShape.Delete
Next theShape

' Check all existing rows in Column K
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow

' the URLs are already computed and stored in column K
URL = wks.Range("K" & i).Value

' try to put the images in column L
Set pasteCell = wks.Range("L" & i)
pasteCell.Select

' Create a Shape for putting the Image into
' ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL).Select is deprecated and does not work any more!!!
Set theShape = wks.Shapes.AddPicture(URL, pasteCell.Left, pasteCell.Top, 200, 200)

' Set shape image backcolor.
theShape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)

Next i

End Sub
```

Your urls will need to be properly formatted - I had to use quotations on my URL for the initial snippet to get it function effectively, but it may be a solution.

For Mac-Excel 2011, there is a workaround discussed by [Michael McLaughlin](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/03/08/add-image-comment-vba/) on his blog. Evidently, it is not easy to tie images to cells in Mac-Excel 2011, if at all. Moreover, research reveals that the question of inserting images into an excel workbook has been asked many times. It also appears that it has not been readily solved through picture methods thus far in the research. Thus, a work-around may be the best solution.

The code snippet, which was very closely adapted and ported from Michael's blog, is as follows:

```
Function InsertImageCommentAsWorkAround(title As String, cellAddress As Range)

    ' Define variables used in the comment.
    Dim ImageCommentContainer As comment

  ' Clear any existing comments before adding new ones.
  Application.ActiveCell.ClearComments

  ' Define the comment as a local variable and assign the file name from the _
  ' _ cellAddress as an input parameter to the comment of a cell at its cellAddress.

  ' Add a comment.
  Set ImageCommentContainer = Application.ActiveCell.AddComment

  ' With the comment, set parameters.
  With ImageCommentContainer
    .Text Text:=""

        'With the shape overlaying the comment, set parameters.
        With .Shape
          .Fill.UserPicture (cellAddress.Value)
          .ScaleHeight 3#, msoFalse, msoScaleFormTopLeft
          .ScaleWidth 2.4, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        End With

  End With

  InsertImageCommentAsWorkAround = title

End Function
```

I would advise adapting the comment sets into your loop, and use that to set your images into place, using the shape formatting in your loop to set the formatting of the comment shapes generated by the adapted code.

Comment: I already tried this, but I got a "Runtime Error 1004 - the file could not be FOUND" when trying to add the picture. 
    
This happens with your stack overflow-URL as well as with http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?_&location=51.501554,-0.178082&size=512x512&heading=135&fov=100&pitch=0&sensor=false
    
You tested with Excel:mac 2011 (VBA Version 14.0.0)?

Comment: Tom, I will do some research on that VBA version - I tested on Excel 2007 without thinking - and you already got it to work that way =).

Comment: Tom, after researching, I found that many others shared this issue ;) I did not find a picture method solution, which have been optimal, but I found a work-around by a Michael McLaughlin, which I have ported closely and directly to my SO post. See if that works as a work-around and let me know of the results.

Comment: I can't believe: it works with Excel:mac 2011!!!

I modified your code (for convenience) corresponding to MacLochlainns Weblog: 

`Function InsertCommentImage(title As String, URL As String)
…
ImageCommentContainer.Shape.Fill.UserPicture(URL)`

and the picture from the URL appears!!!

GREAT!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem =) You should also be aware that Excel-mac 2011 has [some issues](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/11/04/excel-2011-without-udfs/) with [UDFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function) as well, it appears, so be careful when innovating those kewl new functions. Good luck!