# I'm trying to get real time weather in excel from a website but keep getting different run-time errors in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

I am pulling information off of (https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/page/explorer-free) and following a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo5TvtXuzJQ) that says exactly how to do it. Unfortunately, when I run my code at the end in VBA it will say run time error, also my Command Button (ActiveX Control) wont respond at all in excel when I click it. This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet

WS.Range("theDate").Value = ""
WS.Range("highTemps").Value = ""
WS.Range("lowTemps").Value = ""

Dim delShape As Shape
For Each delShape In WS.Shapes
    If delShape.Type = msoAutoShape Then delShape.Delete
Next delShape

Dim Req As New XMLHTTP60
Req.Open "GET", "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Hong%20Kong&format=XML&num_of_days=5&key=d3e0463dc48afecc7815bbf8ffb92", False
Req.send

Dim Resp As New DOMDocument60
Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText

Dim Weather As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Integer
Dim wShape As Shape
Dim thisCell As Range
For Each Weather In Resp.getElementsByTagName("weather")
    i = i + 1
    WS.Range("theDate").Cells(1, i).Value = Weather.SelectNodes("date")(0).Text
    WS.Range("highTemps").Cells(1, i).Value = Weather.SelectNodes("tempMaxF")(0).Text
    WS.Range("lowTemps").Cells(1, i).Value = Weather.SelectNodes("tempMinF")(0).Text
    Set thisCell = WS.Range("weatherPictures").Cells(1, i)

    Set wShape = WS.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, thisCell.Left, thisCell.Top, thisCell.Width, thisCell.Height)
    wShape.Fill.UserPicture Weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl").Item(0).Text

Next Weather
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, I should not that while the red text is showing up correctly on here, when I did this in VBA none of the text was coming out red

Comment: Please read [mcve] and also read the fantastic debugging guide linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: what line of code is giving you the runtime error? And what runtime error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I appreciate that but I dont know what any of that stuff means...I have no experience with VBA and coding in general so I don't know what to even say in order to get answers from people. Im going crazy over here and cant find a fix for this no matter how many web pages I go through....

Comment: MatthewD: Run time error 91 and it highlights the first line, also nothing is highlighted red like it is suppose to be, not sure what that means but it is like it wont connect to the website correctly or something

Comment: Ok.  What reference did you use for the XMLHTTP60?

Comment: Do you mean the URL below it? When I put the info I need in the website it spits out this long code to use and gives you a  call url: (api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Hong%20Kong&format=XML&num_of_days=5&key=d3e0463dc48afecc7815bbf8ffb92)

Comment: No I meant in your IDE under the tools pulldown, the references dialog.  But i found it.  I got it to a point where i am getting an error "Cant connect to server.  But i'm not sure why...

Comment: MattD: Probably because you have to have an account to use the site, it is free but you have to have the code to use the info...what did you do?

Comment: The VBA editor in Excel by default shows comments in green and everything else in blue. The red colour you see on this site is added by StackOverflow's markdown parser which tries to render things from many different programming languages. In Excel's VBA editor, you can use Tools > Options > Editor Format to change the colours if you want

Answer (score 2):

I made these changes above the `Dim Resp As New DOMDocument60`.  That get's me to a cannot make connection to the server.  You may be able to connect with your account with this.

Don't overlook the change of `Dim Req As Object`

```
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet
Dim strResult As String

WS.Range("theDate").Value = ""
WS.Range("highTemps").Value = ""
WS.Range("lowTemps").Value = ""

Dim delShape As Shape
For Each delShape In WS.Shapes
    If delShape.Type = msoAutoShape Then delShape.Delete
Next delShape

Dim Req As Object
Set Req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

Req.Open "GET", "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Hong%20Kong&format=XML&num_of_days=5&key=d3e0463dc48afecc7815bbf8ffb92", False

Req.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
Req.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Req.send

'strResult = Req.responseText
'Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A10:A10") = strResult

Dim Resp As New DOMDocument60
```

**EDIT: for the error setting the usepicture**

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844260/vba-excel-shape).  The shape is being filled with the pic a bit different.  You are declaring your shape, then try doing a `set wShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture`

```
Dim wShape As Shape 
Set wShape  = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl").Item(0).Text, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 100, 100)
```

That is assuming that Weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl").Item(0).Text has the path to a picture.  You will want to verify that.

Comment: Now that I made the change it switches automatically to the (General)/(Declarations) at the top and when I try and run the code it prompts me to give a macro name...when I switch it back (VBA name)/(click) at the top and run it now I get compiling error:invalid outside procedure

Comment: and also now a run-time error 9:subscript out of range

Comment: might this have something to do with the line:                                             strResult = Req.responseText
'Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A10:A10") = strResult

Comment: no, that is just how i was going to write the response to a worksheet.  you can comment that out.

Comment: So unless I include: Private Sub btnRefresh_Click() at the top it automatically switches to General and Declarations at the top and asks for a macro name when I run it...If I include it at the top of the code I get a run-time error 91.....I know you have helped alot and Im not too wise in this category making it extra painful for you so if you want to call it with helping me I completely understand by the way

Comment: Now when I debug the run time error 91 it highlights this row:  WS.Range("highTemps").Cells(1, i).Value = Weather.SelectNodes("tempMaxF")(0).Text

Comment: Also, I don't know what text in the code being red means but in the example I saw on youtube and in the code I copied for this site there was red text, but in my VBA code there is none. Is that important or just something that doesn't effect the outcome?

Comment: @James Roberts: almost all VBA code has to be within a Sub or Function to compile. Every macro has a name and that name comes from the Sub/Function declaration. That's why missing out the `Private Sub...` part gives an error. The colour of the text isn't relevant. Should it be "maxtempF" instead of "tempMaxF"?

Comment: Thanks @barrowc. I didn't realize you had taken the code i posted and had not placed it inside your original sub.  i was just posting the part of your sub I had changed.

Comment: @barrowc and MattewD, first of all thanks for all the help, Im so close to getting this to work. All I am getting now is a runtime error 91 and when I debug it highlights the very last line of code!!                                                           wShape.Fill.UserPicture Weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl").Item(0).Text (all one line)...any thoughts?

Comment: @matthewD: I did know to just put it into my original sub I accidently just left it out at the top, thanks

Comment: @James Roberts See the edit to my answer for your error on the last line.

Comment: @MatthewD: I tried your change but still get the same error (run-time error 91). Also I don't think it has anything to do with this line as a path to the picture <Weather.SelectNodes("weatherIconUrl").Item(0).> because when I run it in excel everything comes out perfectly, exactly as showed, except for the pictures displaying the type of weather which is obviously the last line. How exactly do I go about setting the object variable for this? I already have <Dim wShape As Shape> in the code so it must have something  else to do with how the code is written in the last line right?

Comment: I just found this, not sure if it helps but I think it might. So on the website, the code it provides is what I have been using as references (date, maxtempF, mintempF) for the weatherIconUrl it provides this as well...<weatherIconUrl>
                                                                                                                <![CDATA[http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0033_cloudy_with_light_rain_night.png]]>
        </weatherIconUrl>